How to solve "ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED" error in this code?
When I run this code I get the error:

ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED: You can't specify target table 'Company' for
update in FROM clause

DELETE FROM Company
WHERE name IN (
   SELECT name FROM Company as a
   JOIN Trip ON Trip.company = a.id
   GROUP BY a.name
   HAVING COUNT(Trip.id) = (
       SELECT COUNT(Trip.id) FROM Trip
       JOIN Company as b ON b.id = Trip.company
       GROUP BY b.name
       ORDER BY COUNT(Trip.id) ASC LIMIT 1
    )
)

I have encountered the "ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED" problem before, but for some reason this time it just won't go away. I submitted the "Company" table with a different name, but the error still appeared. What's wrong?

Which dbms are you using? (Product specific syntax, and product specific behavior.)

The innermost subquery looks strange. What are you trying to do? A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

I am completing a task on the site - "Delete companies that have made the fewest trips". The "Company" folder contains the names and IDs of these companies, and "Trip" contains the schedule of the trips themselves

You're trying to delete from a table and simultaneously using that same table in a subquery with the WHERE clause. 
MySQL still treats it as the same table, causing this error.
You should create a derived or temporary table first, then delete it.

But by making the "as a" construction, am I not creating what you are talking about?

The delete is the Outerquery and the Select is the Subquery, you're trying to select from a table you're deleting from.
You can create a derived table and the delete as:
DELETE FROM Company
WHERE name IN (
SELECT name FROM (
SELECT a.name FROM Company as a
JOIN Trip ON Trip.company = a.id
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(Trip.id) = (
SELECT COUNT(Trip.id) FROM Trip
JOIN Company as b ON b.id = Trip.company
GROUP BY b.name
ORDER BY COUNT(Trip.id) ASC LIMIT 1
)
) AS derived_table
)

Thank you very much, it worked. I didn't really understand why it didn't work without this addition though.

MySQL simply doesn't allow a DELETE to interact with a table that is being selected in a subquery. Just rules I guess.
